# Java program to implement Dijkstra not reading txt file

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, dijkstra

Here is my implementation of Dijkstra, based on pseudocode provided in class. (This was a school assignment, but the project has already been turned in by a teammate. I'm just trying to figure out why my version does not work.)

When I create my own graph with the same graph info as the txt file, it gives me the correct output- the shortest path to each vertex from a given source. When I read in a text file, it does not. It reads in the file and prints the correct *adjacency list*, but does not give the shortest paths.

Here's where it goes wrong when it runs on the file: on the first iteration of relax, it updates the adjacent vertex distances and parent, but returns to the dijkstra method and the distance/parent are no longer updated. Why is that?

The provided txt file looks like this:
4
0 1,1 3,2
1 2,4
2 1,6 4,7
3 0,3 1,9 2,2
4 0,10 3,5

Sorry if this is a mess, I'm learning!

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.io.IOException;

/** Class to implement Dijkstra algorithm. 
* Includes classes for Vertex, Edge and Graph. 
*/
public class Dijkstra {
   
   private LinkedList<Vertex> shortestPath;
   private LinkedList<Vertex> path;
   private PriorityQueue<Vertex> pq;
   private PriorityQueue<Vertex> pq2;
   static final int INFINITY = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
   
   /** Main method reads in a txt file and prints
   * the shortest path to each vertex from a given source.
   * @throws FileNotFoundException 
   * @throws IOException
   */
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, 
      IOException {
      // ourGraph is a sample graph to test output
      // vertices and edges are the same as txt file
      Vertex v0 = new Vertex("0");
      Vertex v1 = new Vertex("1");
      Vertex v2 = new Vertex("2");
      Vertex v3 = new Vertex("3");
      Vertex v4 = new Vertex("4");
      Graph ourGraph = new Graph(v4);

      ourGraph.addVertex(v0);
      ourGraph.addVertex(v1);
      ourGraph.addVertex(v2);
      ourGraph.addVertex(v3);
      ourGraph.addVertex(v4);
      
      ourGraph.addEdge(v0, v1, 1);
      ourGraph.addEdge(v0, v3, 2);
      ourGraph.addEdge(v1, v2, 4);
      ourGraph.addEdge(v2, v1, 6);
      ourGraph.addEdge(v2, v4, 7);
      ourGraph.addEdge(v3, v0, 3);
      ourGraph.addEdge(v3, v1, 9);
      ourGraph.addEdge(v3, v2, 2);
      ourGraph.addEdge(v4, v0, 10);
      ourGraph.addEdge(v4, v3, 5);
      ourGraph.printGraph();  // prints correct output
      Dijkstra d = new Dijkstra();
      d.getDijkstra(ourGraph, v4);      // runs Dijkstra with v4 as source
      for (Vertex v : ourGraph.nodes) {
         d.printShortestPath(ourGraph, v); // correct output for shortest paths
      } 
             
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Please enter file name: ");
      String fileName = scanner.nextLine();
        
      Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
      String sourceID = file.nextLine();
        
      Graph g = new Graph(new Vertex(sourceID));
              
      while (file.hasNext()) {
         String[] currentLine = file.nextLine().split(" |,");
         Vertex vertex = new Vertex(currentLine[0]);
         g.addVertex(vertex);
         // set the graph's source vertex
         if (vertex.getName().equals(sourceID)) {
            g.source = vertex;      
         }
         // read current line for adjacent vertices and their edge weights  
         for (int i = 1; i < currentLine.length; i++) {
            g.addEdge(vertex, new Vertex(currentLine[i]), 
               Integer.parseInt(currentLine[++i]));
         }
              
      }
      g.printGraph();   // prints expected graph
        
      Dijkstra d2 = new Dijkstra();
      d2.getDijkstra(g, g.source);    
      for (Vertex vx : g.nodes) {
         d2.printShortestPath(g, vx);
      }
        
   }
   
   /* Vertex class with fields for name, parent,
   * distance, and edge list. 
   */
   static class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex> {
      private String name;
      private Vertex p;
      private int d;
      private LinkedList<Edge> edgeList;
      
      Vertex(String n) {
         this.name = n;
         this.p = null;
         this.d = INFINITY;
         edgeList = new LinkedList<>();
      }
      
      public String getName() {
         return name;
      }
      
      public LinkedList<Edge> getEdges() {
         return edgeList;
  
      }
      @Override
   public int compareTo(Vertex other) {
         return Integer.compare(this.d, other.d);
   
      }
   }
   
   static class Edge {
      private int weight;
      private Vertex source;
      private Vertex destination;
   
   
      Edge(Vertex d, int w) {
         this.destination = d;
         this.weight = w;
      }
   
      public int getWeight() {
         return weight;
      }
      public Vertex getSource() {
         return source;
      }
    
      public Vertex getDestination() {
         return destination;
      }
   }

   static class Graph {
      private LinkedList<Vertex> nodes;
      private Vertex source;
   
      Graph(Vertex s) {
         nodes = new LinkedList<>();
         this.source = s;
                
      }
      public void addSource(Vertex s) {
         this.source = s;
      }
   
      public void addEdge(Vertex s, Vertex d, int weight) {
         s.getEdges().add(new Edge(d, weight));
      }
   
      public void addVertex(Vertex v) {
         nodes.add(v);
      }
   
      public void printGraph() {
         for (Vertex v : nodes) {
            System.out.print("vertex: " + v.getName() + ": ");
            for (Edge e : v.getEdges()) {
               System.out.print(e.getDestination().getName()
                  + "," + e.getWeight() + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
         }
         
      }
   }  
   /** method to calculate shortest path using
   * Dijkstra's algorithm. 
   * @param graph with vertices and edges 
   * @param source as starting vertex
   * @return a LinkedList of vertices as shortest path
   */
   public LinkedList<Vertex> getDijkstra(Graph graph, Vertex source) {
      initializeSingleSource(graph, source);
      shortestPath = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
      
      pq = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
      pq.addAll(graph.nodes);
      while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
// used a second pq to re-min-heapify after min is removed
         pq2 = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
         pq2.addAll(pq);
         Vertex u = pq2.poll();
         if (!shortestPath.contains(u)) {
            shortestPath.add(u);
         }        
         for (Edge e : u.getEdges()) {
            relax(u, e.getDestination(), e.getWeight());
         }
         pq.remove(u);
      }
      return shortestPath;
   }
   /** initializes each vertex distance to infinity and
   * each parent to null. Sets source distance to 0.
   * @param graph for input
   * @param source is source vertex of graph
   */
   public void initializeSingleSource(Graph graph, Vertex source) {
      for (Vertex v : graph.nodes) {
         v.d = INFINITY;
      }
      source.d = 0;
   }
   /** Relax checks if the distance of the destination
   * vertex is greater than the distance of the start plus 
   * the edge weight and updates distance and parent attributes.
   * @param u vertex is start 
   * @param v is destination vertex
   * @param weight is edge weight
   */
   public void relax(Vertex u, Vertex v, int weight) {
      if (v.d > u.d + weight) {
         v.d = u.d + weight;
         v.p = u;
      }
   }

   /** getPath puts shortest path in order for a given target.
   * @param g for graph input
   * @param target is target vertex of shortest path from the
   * graph's source
   * @return LinkedList of shortest path
   */
   public LinkedList<Vertex> getPath(Graph g, Vertex target) {
      LinkedList<Vertex> path = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
      Vertex step = target;
      int i = shortestPath.indexOf(step);
      while (step.p != null) {
         path.add(step);
         step = step.p;
      }
      Collections.reverse(path);
      return path;
   }
   /** prints a formatted list of a single vertex's shortest path.
   * from the graph's source
   * @param g is graph
   * @param target is target vertex of shortest path
   */
   public void printShortestPath(Graph g, Vertex target) {
      shortestPath = getPath(g, target);
      System.out.print(target.getName() + ": "); 
      for (Vertex v : shortestPath) {
         System.out.print(v.getName() + " ");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
   }
     
   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the structure of the file is as follows:

```
4
0 1,1 3,2 
1 2,4
2 1,6 4,7 
3 0,3 1,9 2,2 
4 0,10 3,5
```

Now for your problem here, the cause of this problem is the creation of new vertices when reading the file:

```
while (file.hasNext()) {
    String[] currentLine = file.nextLine().split(" |,");
    Vertex vertex = new Vertex(currentLine[0]);
    g.addVertex(vertex);
    // set the graph's source vertex
    if (vertex.getName().equals(sourceID)) {
        g.source = vertex;
    }
    // read current line for adjacent vertices and their edge weights  
    for (int i = 1; i < currentLine.length; i++) {
        g.addEdge(vertex, new Vertex(currentLine[i]),
        Integer.parseInt(currentLine[++i]));
    }

}
```

when you do:

```
g.addEdge(vertex, new Vertex(currentLine[i]), Integer.parseInt(currentLine[++i]));
```

here you create a new vertex with the name `currentLine[i]` even if there's already one with the same name in the graph, it'll create a new one and will not magically reuse the existing one.

To remedy this problem, add a function in your `Graph` class for example to get an existing vertex by name or create one if it's not found.

In your `Graph` class add the following method:

```
public Vertex getOrCreateVertex(String name) {
    for (Vertex v : nodes) {
        if (v.name.equals(name)) {
            return v;
        }
    }

    Vertex newVertex = new Vertex(name);
    nodes.add(newVertex);
    return newVertex;
}
```

And change the part reading the file as follows:

```
while (file.hasNext()) {
    String[] currentLine = file.nextLine().split(" |,");
    Vertex vertex = g.getOrCreateVertex(currentLine[0]);
    // set the graph's source vertex
    if (vertex.getName().equals(sourceID)) {
        g.source = vertex;
    }
    // read current line for adjacent vertices and their edge weights
    for (int i = 1; i < currentLine.length; i++) {
        g.addEdge(vertex, g.getOrCreateVertex(currentLine[i]),
                Integer.parseInt(currentLine[++i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that did it. Thank you @b.GHILAS !